# x64 and x86 directories naming confusion

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

[image]

I have the following directories output.
Can anybody explain why the folders "Debug" and "Release" aren't named properly with either "x86" or "x64"?

The way it current is, I don't know which version it is.
Is this an intended behaviour or something that was wrecked up during an update from one of the VS versions to a newer one?

Comment: VS2015 is pretty borken, it can't make up its mind if it wants to create a Win32 or an x86 platform.  Never yet saw a pattern, looks random.  But probably has something to do with creating a managed project earlier, I do switch a lot.  It is a bag 'o bugs, just fix it by adding/deleting platforms.

Answer (score 3):

This is legacy, prior to supporting x64, there was just a debug and release directory. When they added x64, they created the x64 directory to house the debug and release directories for those builds, but never modified where x86 builds end up by default. Probably to keep existing projects from having there outputs move after the upgrade.

To organize them by platform in C++ you can alter you project settings like so:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I could setup up VS to produce the x86 and x64 folders? Do I have to re-create my project from scratch instead of having to change the Output Path?

Comment: I personally use a macro along the lines of `@(SolutionDir)@(Platform)\$(Configuration)` for my output directory, and `@(SolutionDir)@(Platform)\$(Configuration)\@(Project)` for my intermediate files

Comment: Of course, as other legacy detail, x86 is called Win32 (at least for C++ projects)

Comment: In my earlier comment, I should have used dollar signs instead of at characters, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the project properties page (right-click the project -> `Properties`) and navigate to the `Build` section, you will see a field called `Output Path`.

This will determine where output binaries will go relative to the project directory. It can be configured individually for each build configuration and build platform by using the two dropdown controls at the top of the page.

It sounds like you would like Debug and Release directories to be placed under x86 and x64 folders, so you'll need to update each of the four combinations of configuration/platform.

- Debug/x86 - "bin\x86\Debug"
- Release/x86 - "bin\x86\Release"
- Debug/x64 - "bin\x64\Debug"
- Release/x64 - "bin\x64\Release"

[image: Output path]